# C# LINQ Expression as parameter for DataTable method

Tags: c#, linq, generic-programming

I have a LINQ expression that I wish to make it become generic :

```
public class GenericBudgetMatrix
    {
        public List<string> MatrixHeaders { set; get; }
        public List<GenericBudgetMatrixRow> MatrixRow { set; get; }
        public GenericBudgetMatrixRow MatrixFooterRow { set; get; }
    }

public class GenericBudgetMatrixRow
{
        public string EntityName { set; get; }
        public List<decimal> Values { set; get; }
        public decimal Total { set; get; }
}

GenericBudgetMatrix _genericBudgetMatrix = new GenericBudgetMatrix();

_genericBudgetMatrix.MatrixRow = _matrixTemplate.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>
                                    new GenericBudgetMatrixRow
                                    {
                                        EntityName = r.Field<string>(0),
                                        Values = r.ItemArray.Skip(1).Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x)).ToList(),
                                        Total = r.ItemArray.Skip(1).Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x)).Sum()
                                    }
                                    ).ToList();
```

I wish to make a new method to accept

```
r =>
     new GenericBudgetMatrixRow
     {
        EntityName = r.Field<string>(0),
        Values = r.ItemArray.Skip(1).Select(x => 
                    Convert.ToDecimal(x)).ToList(),
                    Total = r.ItemArray.Skip(1).Select(x => 
                     Convert.ToDecimal(x)).Sum()
                                        }
```

as a Func expression parameter.

Something like this :

```
public void GenericMethod(Func<expression> predicate, DataTable _matrixTemplate)
{
    _matrixTemplate.AsEnumerable().Select(predicate).ToList();
}
```

Any ideas that can help me build this approach?

Answer (score 2):

`Select` expects a `Func<T, TResult>`, so you should provide it as parameter to your method:

```
public void GenericMethod<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> predicate, DataTable _matrixTemplate)
{
    _matrixTemplate.AsEnumerable().Select(predicate).ToList();
}
```

Furthermore I guess your method should return the result of your selection, so turn it into a method returning instances of `TResult`(which in your case is `GenericBudgetMatrixRow`). Last but not least the call to `ToList` is obsolete as you´re doing this in your calling code anyway. Thus return an `IEnumerable<TResult>` instead:

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> GenericMethod<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> predicate, DataTable _matrixTemplate)
{
    return _matrixTemplate.AsEnumerable().Select(predicate);
}
```

Now you cann call it like this:

```
_genericBudgetMatrix.MatrixRow = GenericMethod(
    r => new GenericBudgetMatrixRow
        {
            EntityName = r.Field<string>(0),
            Values = r.ItemArray.Skip(1).Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x)).ToList(),
            Total = r.ItemArray.Skip(1).Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x)).Sum()
        }, 
    _matrixTemplate)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You return `IEnumerable` but call `ToList()`, looks strange. I suggest remove `ToList()` and return pure `IEnumerable` or change return type to `List` or `IList`.

Comment: @santi Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: The error mentioned that : 'EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'Select; and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Select<T, TResult>(ParallelQuery<T>, Func<T,TResult>)>' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery<T>'

Comment: public IEnumerable<TResult> GenericMethod<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> predicate, DataTable _matrixTemplate)
{
    return _matrixTemplate.AsEnumerable().Select(predicate);
}

Comment: @HimBromBeere, i checked on the 

public static EnumerableRowCollection<S> Select<TRow, S>(this EnumerableRowCollection<TRow> source, Func<TRow, S> selector),

doesn't seems like the predicate with wrong type . Any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution already. It is due to the Generic Type

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> GenericMethod(Func<DataRow, TResult> predicate, DataTable _matrixTemplate)
{
    return _matrixTemplate.AsEnumerable().Select(predicate);
}
```